# Nested resource (with custom controller param) has named helpers that don't generate URLs properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a really strange issue with named helpers. So let's start off with the routes in question:

```
  resources :subjects, path: 'library' do
    resources :modules, controller: 'subject_modules'
  end
```

Where `Subjects#to_param` returns `self.slug`. Now, for a subject named "Foo" and module with id 1, where the subject is `@subject` and module is `m`:

- `link_to subject_modules_path(@subject, m)` gives /library/foo/modules.1
- `link_to edit_subject_module_path(@subject, m)` gives /library/foo/modules/1/edit
- `link_to m` gives /library/1/modules/physics

As for `link_to [@subject, m]`, I get:

> Routing Error
>
> ```
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"subject_modules", :subject_id=>#<Subject id: 2, name: "Foo", created_at: "2011-12-30 02:00:38", updated_at: "2011-12-30 02:00:38", slug: "foo">, :id=>#<SubjectModule ---snipped--->}
> ```

Does anyone know why the routes are broken the way they are, and what I could possibly do to fix this?

**EDIT:**

Rake routes:

```
    subject_modules GET    /library/:subject_id/modules(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"subject_modules"}
                    POST   /library/:subject_id/modules(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"subject_modules"}
 new_subject_module GET    /library/:subject_id/modules/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"subject_modules"}
edit_subject_module GET    /library/:subject_id/modules/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"subject_modules"}
     subject_module GET    /library/:subject_id/modules/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"subject_modules"}
                    PUT    /library/:subject_id/modules/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"subject_modules"}
                    DELETE /library/:subject_id/modules/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"subject_modules"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be some quirk in Rails' routing system currently.

Using `subject_module_path(@subject, m)` initially caused a "can't find route" error for me (which I tried at the time I wrote the question), but it somehow worked eventually.

I can't pinpoint this issue so unfortunately I have no idea of its cause. This problem happened with Rails 3.1.3.

Comment: You probably restarted your server which made Rails co-operate.

Comment: @RyanBigg Doesn't Rails automatically regenerate things when it's in devmode and detects changes in files though?

Comment: It has some quirks to it and sometimes doesn't detect these changes. No way of knowing if this was or wasn't the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Can you check if using "rake routes" that your helper points to the correct Url ?

Comment: Yep. `[@subject, m]` doesn't use a helper method so that isn't applicable for that case.